# axtls ssl_client_new double free or corruption

Tags: ssl

I have a small problem with AXTLS. I'm trying to establish a SSL communication with a server, but it looks like it double-frees something in "ssl_client_new" function.

The code creates a new ctx (ssl_ctx_new) and loads the certificates (ssl_obj_load) during initialization (no problem here), the socket is connected and when I call "ssl_client_new", libc detects a double free:

> "double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x0809f740"

I started the application under gdb, and this is the backtrace:

```
Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted. 0xb7fdd424 in
__kernel_vsyscall () (gdb) bt
#0  0xb7fdd424 in __kernel_vsyscall ()
#1  0xb7d371ef in __GI_raise (sig=6) at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:64
#2  0xb7d3a835 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:91
#3  0xb7d722fa in __libc_message (do_abort=2, fmt=0xb7e6a3bc "*** glibc detected *** %s: %s: 0x%s ***\n") at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/libc_fatal.c:201
#4  0xb7d7ce42 in malloc_printerr (action=<optimized out>, str=<optimized out>, ptr=0x809f740) at malloc.c:5007
#5  0x080712fd in asn1_name ()
#6  0x0806849f in x509_new ()
#7  0x080642cc in process_certificate ()
#8  0x08067caa in do_clnt_handshake ()
#9  0x08066675 in basic_read ()
#10 0x08067a07 in ssl_client_new ()
```

The ctx pointer and the sockets are ok, and last two parameters are NULL and 0. (http://axtls.sourceforge.net/dox/group_*c*_api.html#ga4eef242a559b06d72b862c1e5ab3d0a2)

Here is the strace for my socket:

```
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 8

fcntl64(8, F_GETFL)                     = 0x2 (flags O_RDWR)
fcntl64(8, F_SETFL, O_RDWR|O_NONBLOCK)  = 0
connect(8, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(443), sin_addr=inet_addr("81.12.132.173")}, 16) = -1 EINPROGRESS (Operation now in progress)
select(9, NULL, [8], NULL, {10, 0})     = 1 (out [8], left {9, 996818})
getsockopt(8, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, [0], [4]) = 0
fcntl64(8, F_SETFL, O_RDWR)             = 0

fcntl64(8, F_GETFL)                     = 0x2 (flags O_RDWR)
fcntl64(8, F_SETFL, O_RDWR)             = 0

write(8, "\26\3\1\0003\1\0\0/\3\1P@hf?\222Y\3046n\215\364\317\34-D8\311\270=\225"..., 56) = 56
read(8, "\26\3\1\0J", 5)                = 5
read(8, "\2\0\0F\3\1Q\301_\210\267\200\352*}H\330\265\n;\33\253\31\24\320\377+\3\371\276g\362"..., 74) = 74

read(8, "\26\3\1\20)", 5)               = 5
read(8, "\v\0\20%\0\20\"\0\5\0070\202\5\0030\202\3\353\240\3\2\1\2\2\23w\0\0~\263\3446"..., 4137) = 2632
read(8, "1\0270\25\6\3U\4\n\f\16Vodafone Group1)0'\6\3U"..., 1505) = 1505
```

So ssl handshake started.
And immediatly after this:

```
open("/dev/tty", O_RDWR|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK) = 9
writev(9, [{"*** glibc detected *** ", 23}, {"./HTTPS_TOOL", 11}, {": ", 2}, {"double free or corruption (fastt"..., 35}, {": 0x", 4}, {"082ba740", 8}, {" ***\n", 5}], 7*** glibc detected *** ./HTTPS_TOOL: double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x082ba740 ***
) = 88
```

Any ideas? Which can be the problem and what can I do?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you still getting the issue? I haven't had any reports of this and it may be a way the library is being used.

The library has been checked many times in Valgrind and there aren't any recent issues. Could you perhaps run it in Valgrind to verify?